# Suffixed macro and uppercase

Tags: macros

when I declare a macro with suffix, its use inside a `\uppercase` commands doesn't work.

See the MWE

```
\documenclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\AcCan}{\emph{Actes des Apôtres} canoniques}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\AcCan*{\emph{Actes des Apôtres}}

{\MakeUppercase{Les \AcCan}}
\end{document}
```

If delete the `\WithSuffix` line, it's ok.

Comment: That isn't a MWE, it just generates `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`

Comment: you are right. I have forgotten to copy it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method which will allow you to still use `\AcCan` and `\AcCan*`, without extra braces. See the small caveat in the code comments and below.

*Extra caveat added in update*

```
% -*- coding: iso-latin-1; -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% First we patch LaTeX \MakeUppercase and \MakeLowercase
% As far as I can tell, these redefinitions should have nil impact 
% and very few incompatibilies, if any.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{%
      \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1\empty}}% \empty added
      \reserved@a
   }}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeLowercase}[1]{{%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##2##1\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\lowercase{#1\empty}}% \empty added
      \reserved@a
   }}
\makeatother

% Then we can define expandable variant \AcCan* 
% The collateral effect is that \AcCan act as a brace remover: just be aware
% that \AcCan {<stuff>} will be as original \AcCan <stuff> and never use
% \AcCan {stuff * more stuff} as it will end up in error: I am perhaps not  
% providing it the most robust way (and I don't use e-TeX whose \detokenize
%  would help for alternatives), but in 99% of cases it should be ok.

% Important caveat: if \AcCan is used as part of the argument of a macro,
% like \section then, if it *last* therein before the closing }, it *must* 
% be followed by {}, or \empty, or \relax.

\catcode`_ 11
% helper macro,
\long\def\GobToStar #1*{}
% expandably enhancing \AcCan with a starred variant
\long\def\AcCan #1{\GobToStar #1\AcCan_s *\AcCan_ns #1}
% the \long is in case \AcCan is last on a line, itself followed by empty line.
\def\AcCan_s *\AcCan_ns *{\emph{Actes des Apôtres}}% starred variant
\def\AcCan_ns {\emph{Actes des Apôtres} canoniques}% non starred variant
%
% The above could easily be automatized:
% \MakeStarredVariant\Macro{replacement text for \Macro*}
% with the same limitations as pointed above
%
\catcode`_ 8

\begin{document}

\AcCan

\AcCan*

\MakeUppercase{\AcCan}

\MakeUppercase{\AcCan*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I said `in 99% of the cases it should be OK`, this just meant: avoid input like `\AcCan {stuff}` (`\AcCan*{stuff}` has no issue  and `\AcCan {stuff}` is a problem only if `stuff` contains `*`.) In general this will be automatic because I guess `AcCan` will be followed either by a letter, punctuation sign, or `\par`, or `}` if used in `\section` for example.

**Important**: in the latter case, (*last* argument in `\section`) or more generally whenever `\AcCan` is a last component of some argument to some macro `\macro {....\AcCan }`, it is recommended to follow it by `{}`, or `\empty` or `\relax`:

`\macro {....\AcCan{}}`

This is mandatory for `\section` for example. For `\textbf` however it is not needed (because internally we will not end up in a situation `\AcCan}` where expanding `\AcCan` will raise an error).

If used as last argument to a macro, even not writing to a file, there is also a smallish risk that the macro will itself add some `{stuff}` after `\AcCan` before expanding `\AcCan`. If `stuff` contains a `*` there will be a problem. The possibility appears remote. In case of a compilation error in such an unlikely situation, replace `\AcCan` by `\AcCan {}` or `\AcCan\empty` and it should be fine. (except if the macro is very obstinate in doing bad things)

The `\AcCan` will be expanded whenever written to the `aux` (hence to the `toc`, it first goes to the `aux`) file, which appears to be no problem either: at this time it will once and for all look for a `*` and expand to one of the two possibilities.

But one must pay attention to cases when it is the *last* piece in the macro argument. Follow it by `{}`, `\empty` or `\relax` then.

Comment: I am quite anxious to redefine \MakeUpperCase....

Comment: The redefinition is truly benign. It adds a single `\empty` token which will disappear. The modification can only break macros designed to be used as the very last piece of an argument to `\MakeUppercase`. It is improbable such a thing exist.

Comment: I will think at what is better in my case, because in any case I should change some line in my main text (indeed, I wanted to do something like `\section{\AcCan*}`.

Comment: `\section{\AcCan*}` is ok, it is only `\section{\AcCan}` which should be replaced by `\section{\AcCan{}}` for example.

Comment: Ok ! But as I see, your solution make create two new commands `\AcCan_s` and `\AcCan_ns`. So I could call them directly in `section`... I any case, thanks. I think you'r solution is the best for using only one command with starred variant.

Comment: `\AcCan_s` will cause you problems because you must change the catcode of `_`. You could drop the `_` but then `\AcCan_s` is a delimited macro, hence you would have to fetch it with what it expects (`* \AcCan_ns*`)

Comment: I was thinking something like `\def\AcCans{starred version}` and `\def\AcCanns{not starred version}` and call `\section{\AcCans}`

Comment: Well, if you are ready to use an `\AcCans`, then there is no need to bother about re-defining `\AcCan` to allow `\AcCan*` ... no more `\AcCan*` only `\AcCans` .. simple and easy .. `:-)`

Comment: there is because I have some text where I use AcCan* and I don't want to make any mistake ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you do `\show\AcCan` after the `\WithSuffix` line, you see

```
> \AcCan=\protected macro:
->\WSF@suffixcheck \AcCan .
```

which means that `\AcCan` survives unchanged an `\edef`, which is what `\MakeUppercase` does to its argument (in the `\protected@edef` form).

Thus the `\uppercase` that's eventually performed still sees `\AcCan` and so does nothing to it.

If you are willing to accept writing `\AcCan{}` and `\AcCan*{}` then you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\AcCan}{sm}{%
  \emph{Actes des Apôtres}%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{ canoniques}%
}

\begin{document}

{\MakeUppercase{Les \AcCan{}}}

{\MakeUppercase{Les \AcCan*{}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, but is there any solution? I can't expand \AcCan before \MakeUppercase (or I am not able with \expandafter)

Comment: @Maïeul Not that I see. If the macro had a mandatory argument something could be done.

Comment: ok, but it's not the case

Comment: @Maïeul If you accept writing `\AcCan{}` and `\AcCan*{}`, then something is possible.

Comment: Yes, I have to look how many time I use the shorter form, without arg. Because I wouldn't like to have to made many change. For the present case, I have avoided the problem by typesetting directly `\emph{Actes des apôtres}` and not `\AcCan*`